# Why do I get the error "Name node can't be used with 'None' constant" when I try to run Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, python-3.8

I am trying to setup odoo on my mac by following the instructions linked on the github page. When starting the server using this command:

```bash
python3 odoo-bin --addons-path=addons -d mydb -i base
```

The server starts and I see one database "mydb" on the odoo splash page. Then when I click that database I get the following error:

```
ERROR mydb werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 439, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
        result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1287, in __call__
        return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1257, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1457, in dispatch
        result = ir_http._dispatch()
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 21, in _dispatch
        return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 238, in _dispatch
        return cls._handle_exception(e)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 206, in _handle_exception
        return request._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 750, in _handle_exception
        return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
        raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 234, in _dispatch
        result = request.dispatch()
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 809, in dispatch
        r = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 342, in checked_call
        result.flatten()
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1236, in flatten
        self.response.append(self.render())
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1229, in render
        return env["ir.ui.view"].render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1177, in render_template
        return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
        return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1185, in render
        return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 58, in render
        result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 260, in render
        self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
      File "<decorator-gen-53>", line 2, in compile
        
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
        value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 113, in compile
        return super(IrQWeb, self).compile(id_or_xml_id, options=options)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 323, in compile
        raise QWebException("Error when compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
    odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: Name node can't be used with 'None' constant
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
        r = d[key]
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
        a = self.d[obj].me
    KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb.compile at 0x7f9436306310>, 196, ('en_US', None, None, None, None, None))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/[username]/Documents/GitHub/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 315, in compile
        unsafe_eval(compile(astmod, '<template>', 'exec'), ns)
    ValueError: Name node can't be used with 'None' constant
    
    Error when compiling AST
    ValueError: Name node can't be used with 'None' constant
    Template: web.login
    Path: /t/t/form/input[2]
    Node: <input type="hidden" name="redirect" t-att-value="redirect"/> - - -
```

I don't know where to start with this error. I have looked up the web.login template and didnt find anything.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Odoo. It was probably silent before but it is now causing a crash since a recent version of Python 3.8. You could downgrade to an earlier version (like python-3.8.3) temporarily until Odoo is fixed.

More [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/54785)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue is to downgrade the version of python you are running on. If suppose you are running on python3.8, you should downgrade to python 3.6 as explained by Husain Rangwala in this article https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/valueerror-name-node-can-t-be-used-with-none-constant-template-1105-path-templates-t-t-div-t-t-after-updating-to-python-3-8-5-177836. To switch between python versions, visit https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/